# Создание списка со значениями 001000 - 999999

Tags: python

Как создать список с номера 001000 до 999999. Я пытался создавать при помощи range:

```
x = (for i in range(1000, 1000000)
```

Но я не понимаю, каким образом сделать так, чтобы перед значением "1000" вставить 2 ноля, чтобы было значение "001000" Именно чтобы каждый номер был бы 6-ти значным.

Comment: Зачем удалили свой такой же вопрос и создали новый? В прошлом был ответ.

Comment: Вы знаете, администратор удалил, т.к. примера кода не было.  Пришлось новый создать. Благодарю Вас, за помощь. А другие варианты возможны? Ваш вариант x:06d in range (1000 - 999999) мы еще теорию не проходили.

Comment: А что вы проходили? Потому как это делается преобразованием элементов списка в строки с форматированием. И вообще, если это часть какой-то более объёмной задачи, может вообще не требуется создавать список.

Comment: Задача была, следующая: Подсчитать % счастливых шестизначных трамвайных билетиков.
# Билет является счастливым, если сумма его первых трёх цифр равна сумме последних трёх цифр.
# Например, 109208 и 334505 - счастливые, 123456 - нет. Номера билетиков лежат в диапазоне 001000 до 999999.
# Ответ написать с точностью до 1 знака после запятой, вида: "Процент счастливых билетиков 2.1%"  .   Я новичек, и мы прошли создание списков, range, базовые вещи. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну вот видите, как это часто бывает, решаем вопрос который к решению задачи совершенно не относится. Но форматирование строк всё же нужно чтобы вывести число с плавающей точкой в нужном вам виде.

Comment: Количество нулей перед значением никак не влияет на сумму, поэтому добавлять их не имеет практического смысла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как это часто бывает, исходная задача совсем другая и не требует ответа на вопрос, который был задан.

Итак, задача:

> Подсчитать % счастливых шестизначных трамвайных билетиков. Билет
> является счастливым, если сумма его первых трёх цифр равна сумме
> последних трёх цифр. Например, 109208 и 334505 - счастливые,
> 123456 - нет. Номера билетиков лежат в диапазоне 001000 до 999999.
> Ответ написать с точностью до 1 знака после запятой, вида:
> "Процент счастливых билетиков 2.1%".

Для этого надо просто подсчитать сумму 3 младших цифр числа (для этого взять остаток от деления числа на 1000) и 3 старших цифр числа (для этого поделить число на 1000 чтобы использовать ту же функцию).

```
def summ3(number):
    d1 = number % 10           # младшая цифра из трёх
    d2 = number //  10 % 10    # средняя цифра из трёх
    d3 = number // 100 % 10    # старшая цифра из трёх
    return d1 + d2 + d3

lucky_counter = 0
for i in range(1000, 1000000):
    if summ3(i % 1000) == summ3(i // 1000):
        lucky_counter += 1

lucky_proc = lucky_counter * 100 / (1000000 - 1000)

print("Всего билетов:", 1000000 - 1000)
print(f"Счастливых билетов: {lucky_counter} штук, {lucky_proc:.1f}%" )
```

Вывод:

```
Всего билетов: 999000
Счастливых билетов: 55251 штук, 5.5%
```

Ну и альтернативные варианты подсчёта суммы цифр числа:

```
# универсальный вариант подсчёта суммы цифр любого числа
def summ3(number):
    s = 0
    while number:
        s += number % 10
        number //= 10
    return s
```

```
# вариант используя функцию sum() с разбивкой числа на цифры через строку
def summ3(number):
    return sum(map(int, str(number)))
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для заполнения слева 0 можно использовать функцию строки `zfill`:

```
items = [f'{i}'.zfill(6) for i in range(1000, 1000000)]
print(items[:10])
# ['001000', '001001', '001002', '001003', '001004', '001005', '001006', '001007', '001008', '001009']
```

Либо использовать форматирование, указав с какой стороны заполнять, каким символом и до какой длины:

```
items = [f'{i:>06}' for i in range(1000, 1000000)]
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Спасибо

Comment: @АндрейКривошеин, пожалуйста, если мой ответ помог, поставьте ему +1 и примите его :)